# problems with Promises (nodejs, bluebird): process exits wihtout waiting for childs to be finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am new to Promises and I am definitely writing incorrect code (I do not yet understand how Promises work).

From the code below I expect that `process.exit(0);` would be executed only when everyting else would be finished.

But in the code below "console.log(`step 2`)" is never executed (seen in console), because I think `process.exit(0)` is run before waiting for other processes. Any suggestoins how to restructure my code?

```
var wordsToProcess = ['e301', 'e260']; // array with many words (could be mora than 2)
var actions = wordsToProcess.map((str) => {
    console.log('(1) step ');
    ingredient_get(str) 
        .then((ingredient_id) => {            
            console.log('(2) step '); //!!!! never console.log
            return ingredient_id;     // never return ingredient_id
        });
});
var results = Promise.all(actions);
results.then(ingredient_id => {    
    process.exit(0); // should somehow wait for all ingredient_ids to come
});

function ingredient_get(name) {
    var q_ingredients = knex('ingredients')
        .select('id').where('name', name)
        .then(pick_id)

    var q_synonyms = knex('synonyms')
        .select('ingredient_id as id').where('name', name)
        .then(pick_id)

    return Promise.all([q_ingredients, q_synonyms])
        .then(([id1, id2]) => {                
            return id1 || id2; // only one id would be true here
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a tiny mistake, nearly a typo: You're missing a `return` in your `map` callback:

```
var actions = wordsToProcess.map((str) => {
    console.log('(1) step ');
    return ingredient_get(str)
//  ^^^^^^------------------------------------ add this
        .then((ingredient_id) => {            
            console.log('(2) step ');
            return ingredient_id;
        });
});
```

Consequently, `actions` is just filled with `undefined` instead of refeernces to promises, so there's nothing for `Promise.all`'s promise to wait for.

If you remove the `console.log` (or abuse the comma operator, but...don't), you can use a concise arrow instead:

```
var actions = wordsToProcess.map((str) =>
    ingredient_get(str)
        .then((ingredient_id) => {            
            console.log('(2) step ');
            return ingredient_id;
        })
);
```

(In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if you *started out* with a concise arrow, then went back and added the logging line and converted it to a verbose arrow but forgot to add the `return`. It's a common error.)

Comment: Seems, that it works. For me all this Promise / async staff is confusing, but this time the problem was "typo".